# How to access Bigquery using key

Tags: google-bigquery

I was given a key which happens to be a .json file to access a bigquery data but I have no idea where to put it and how I should use it. I tried to go to the bigquery console but I can't seem to find where I can place the key to view their data. I have no experience using bigquery so I tried to search for any tutorials to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume that you have created [service account key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) with assigned [roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) (i.e. `roles/bigquery.admin`) and downloaded a JSON file that contains your key.

You will need to use it only whenever you decide to use BigQuery API by using [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python), such as Python or Java. As you can see in the documentation, you need to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the JSON file that contains your service account key to be able to access Bigquery resources.

When using the web UI in the Google Cloud Console, you don't need to use JSON key file. You only need to take care of assigning appropriate roles to the service account you have created. Please take a look for the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-web-ui).

Additionally, I would like to share with you the [introduction to authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication), which is really important.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.